# MongoDB JSON or BSON?

Tags: mongodb

I'm just learning MongoDB but I'm a bit puzzled about the data format accepted by MongoDB. So I understand that by definition:

> "MongoDB doesn’t actually use JSON to store the data; rather, it uses
>   an open data format developed by the MongoDB team called BSON"

That's clear, however I have just learnt that you can actually import a JSON document into mongodb. So is it correct to say that you can use JSON format to insert data into MongoDB but data internally is arranged into BSON for performance reasons ? Hope that somebody can shed some light on it.

Comment: BSON also con­tains ex­ten­sions that al­low rep­res­ent­a­tion of data types that are not part of the JSON spec. Check: http://bsonspec.org/

Comment: FWIW, a similar analogy would be that you can import tabular data (eg. CSV files) into a relational database table. It might be convenient to think of the data structure as CSV-like rows & columns, but the wire protocol and storage format can be quite different from the input and query formats. BSON (Binary JSON) is "JSON-like" in that both can represent similar data structures, but BSON uses a binary format (JSON is text) and can represent richer data types (for example 32-bit ints vs 64-bit ints vs doubles; JSON only has a generic Number type which is a double).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. MongoDB uses BSON to increase performance. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/.

There are various [drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) that make it easy to work with MongoDB. In most cases you dont have to worry about BSON, since it is handled for you.

Comment: Thanks! Just a note, also the result from queries in MongoDB is pure JSON, right ?

Comment: yes the input and output of MongoDB is JSON, just the internal not visible storage format is BSON.

Comment: @Simulant no, the driver deserialises the BSON to JSON syntax for the shell, however, normally the driver will deserialise to the languages own primative objects such as dictionary or object. All communication is in BSON

Comment: BTW you can use Robomongo to manage and run queries on MongoDb: http://robomongo.org/. Provides a nice visual view of stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

Not really for "performance".

BSON is an explanative version of JSON which allows the storage and manipulation of objects such as `ISODate` and `OjbectId`. It allows for MongoDB to produe a syntax and object rich document beyond what JSON can.

BSON normally takes more space than JSON due to its object usage and what not as such there is no serious performance gain. It is about the descriptive objects that can be used and sored with the document.

MongoDB communicates entirely in BSON, including query results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however not sure by what you mean from "including query results". Assumed that this is JSON {"hello": "world"} and this is the corresponding BSON:   \x16\x00\x00\x00                    
  \x02                                
  hello\x00                          
  \x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00         
  \x00 I would say (as newbie) that query results is JSON with an unique identifier.

Comment: @user2824073 In basic form BSON and JSON are very similar, why not try: `{_id: ObjectId('3445656567')}` instead?

Comment: @user2824073 or better yet data specific fields, also getting length of fields, also quite a few other things

Answer (score 1):

When we are using mongodb that time we input json data but mongodb driver can convert it to bson data. it's faster more efficient for space also format size. For more information check this official documents:  https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson . For Know more about Bson Data type check this official link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/